# Titanium Alloy MArkup

Tags: titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy

Iam Working on titanium 3.0 MVC architectture app project. In views we use alloy markup in titanium But how it will support multiple devices with different sizes and resolutions. I tried hard and did't find any solution. I tested app on different devices but UI is not aligned properly in all devices. Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 1):

You support multiple devices with different screen sizes with the way that you design your app. By using the TSS stylesheets (similar to CSS) you set the look and feel for the formfactor (iPhone, iPad, Android, web, Blackberry, tizen). Android requires a lot more images in the assets folder for the resolution of the splash screen so keeping that in mind when you have your images that you want to use in your app remember to GO BIG! You can scale it down within the app. Don't use images that will work on your phone and when displayed on an android tablet they look like tiny icons.

I've been using Titanium for almost a year now and it's just gotten better and better!

Without knowing an exact problem it would be hard to answer but you probably need to set your width or height to `Ti.UI.FILL` or `Ti.UI.SIZE`.

Comment: you dont want to go big, it will impact the performance of the application. You want to specify the appropriate sized assets based on the specific device

Answer (score 0):

Please read the [Style and Themes](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/guide/Alloy_Styles_and_Themes) section of the Alloy documentation. It covers this topic at both a high and low level.